# Let $f$ be periodic with a continuous image and $a_n = cn$ for some $c > 0$. When is $\{f(a_n)\}$ dense in the image of $f$?

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a periodic function with period $T$ and continuous everywhere except perhaps on a countable set, and have an image that's an uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $a_n  = cn$ for some $c > 0$. When is the subset $\{f(a_n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ dense in the image of $f$?

Comment: What is a "continuous image"?

Comment: A non-countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$, like an interval. A better word escapes me, other than "non-countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$".

Comment: I'd reformulate as follows: let $f:\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}\to\mathbf{R}$ be a function whose domain of continuity has a countable complement. Let $c$ be irrational. Is $f(cn)_{n\ge 0}$ dense in $f(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})$?

Comment: Quite clearly there are counterexamples and you should probably rather ask whether the closure of your subset has countable complement in the closure of $\mathrm{Im}(f)$ (indeed, modify a bounded continuous function on a closed countable subset disjoint from the given arithmetic sequence...)